# How to get a list of available network providers?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a list of the available cellular network providers. Unfortunately I can't find any service or class that might help me out.  Does anyone have an idea on how to manage this?  It has to be possible since you can see the list when you go to the settings on your Android device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Android is open source I had a look at the sources and finally found something called **INetworkQueryService**. I guess you can do the same as [the android settings implementation](https://github.com/dzo/packages_apps_phone/blob/master/src/com/android/phone/NetworkSetting.java) and interact with this service:
Some guidance through NetworkSettings.java:

- onCreate starts the NetworkQueryService and binds it
- loadNetworksList() tells the service to query for network operators
- INetworkQueryServiceCallback is evalutated and if the event "EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED" was raised, networksListLoaded will be called to iterate over the available Networks

Comment: wow, i thought that there must be an easier way to do this. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: bro how to start the NetworkQueryService in the onCreate can you give any example?