# How to detect Network operators programmatically on Android?

Tags: android, mobile-development

Is it possible to identify currently attached mobile network and network operators programmatically on Android?
If it is possible please provide code samples

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Try this,

```
// Get System TELEPHONY service reference
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get carrier name (Network Operator Name)
String carrierName = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

// Get Phone model and manufacturer name
 String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
 String model = Build.MODEL;
```

Required Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
  public String getNetworkOperatorName(){
        TelephonyManager tm =
            (TelephonyManager)mCtx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return(tm.getNetworkOperatorName());
    }
```

You can use this for more [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

To get more details about networks:

```
// Get the connected network operator ID (MCC + MNC)
String networkOperatorId = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();

// Get the connected network operator name
String networkName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

// Get the type of network you are connected with 
int networkType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
switch (networkType) {
case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT) :" Block of Code ":
break;
case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA) :"  Block of Code ":
break;
case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE) : "  Block of Code ":
break;
case (TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0) :"  Block of Code ":
break;
```

Comment: Yes, This will return attached Network Operator, apart from that, Is it possible to get all the other available network operators? Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for network operators then this may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454388/android-how-do-i-get-gsm-signal-strength-for-all-available-network-operators]. As in this link, you can use INetworkQueryService to load network list and then display all the available networks.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it myself, but take a look at  [TelephonyManager->](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName())

```
// Get System TELEPHONY service reference
    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // Get Mobile No 

    String mPhoneNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();

    // Get carrier name (Network Operator Name)
    String carrierName = tManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

    // Get Phone model and manufacturer name
     String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
     String model = Build.MODEL;
```

Required Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getOutput(Context context, String methodName, int slotId) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Class<?> telephonyClass;
    String reflectionMethod = null;
    String output = "";
    try {
        telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        for (Method method : telephonyClass.getMethods()) {
            String name = method.getName();
            if (name.contains(methodName)) {
                Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1 && params[0].getName().equals("int")) {
                    reflectionMethod = name;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (reflectionMethod != null) {
        try {
            output = getOpByReflection(telephony, reflectionMethod, slotId, false);
            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

---

```
  private static String getOpByReflection(TelephonyManager telephony, String predictedMethodName, int slotID, boolean isPrivate) {

    Log.i("Reflection", "Method: " + predictedMethodName+" "+slotID);
    String result = null;

    try {

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID;
        if (slotID != -1) {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
            }
        } else {
            if (isPrivate) {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod(predictedMethodName);
            } else {
                getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName);
            }
        }

        Object ob_phone;
        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        if (getSimID != null) {
            if (slotID != -1) {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);
            } else {
                ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony);
            }

            if (ob_phone != null) {
                result = ob_phone.toString();

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Log.i("Reflection", "Result: " + result);
    return result;
}
```