# Android UI customization based on the network operator

Tags: android

I need to customize my Android application's UI based on the SIM operator that is inserted in my phone. For example, If I insert airtel, I need to get yellow UI with yellow launcher icon. For Vodafone I need to get purple UI with purple launcher icon.

Is it possible to point to different resource folder based on the operator in my phone? or How else to customize the theme?  How else to achieve this?

Comment: have a look here on how to the get the carrier name -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938430/how-to-detect-network-operators-programmatically-on-android

Comment: have a look at this [post](http://androidexample.com/How_to_get_SIM_details_in_android/question_answer.php?view=qad&token=33)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It's simply possible!

- First create multiple layout xml files (for each operator).
- Then determine which operator you're using.

  ```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  String opName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
  ```
- Now, apply the layout based on the name of operator.

  ```
  if(opName.equals("vodafone")){
        setContentView(R.layout.vodafone_layout);
  }
  ```

Using the approach discussed above, you can have multiple (potentially different layout structure and widgets per operator) layouts for each operator. If you want to only change *theme* for each operator a better way would be using `setTheme()` before calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: @Ajitha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android

Comment: The above link changes only the shortcut icon and not the appdrawer icon in the application tray :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get carrier's name by using following code

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) 
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

And once you have the name you can compare the string with predefined name string and then change color accordingly

Comment: ok fine thanks. If I want to change entire resource folder based on operator. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can . You have to manually change all images

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources
Can use mcc mnc combination with layout folder to specify region specific and operator specific customization for layout files.