# Android: Fetch all nearby cellular carriers and their signal strength

Tags: android, telephony

I want to fetch all nearby cellular carriers and their signal strength on Android programmatically.
Using `PhoneStateListener`, I was able to get the signal strength of the carrier on which I am currently registered, but I did not find a way to find the signal strength of the other carriers in the vicinity.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: dup : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454388/android-how-do-i-get-gsm-signal-strength-for-all-available-network-operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454388/android-how-do-i-get-gsm-signal-strength-for-all-available-network-operators)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this for getting cellular carrier name

// Get System TELEPHONY service reference
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// Get carrier name (Network Operator Name)
String carrierName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

For getting Signal Strength


TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);`

CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);

CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();

cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

Hope it may be help you