# Search for all available mobile network operators

Tags: android, telephony

I am creating an app to search for all avaialable mobile networks.
The code i use is to direct to mobile networks screen:

```
intent=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have to select "Search Networks" Manually to search for all available networks.
Is there a way to do that programatically. I cant find a solution to INetworkQueryService so if you have a code ready to this please tell!

Answer (score 1):

Since Android is open source you can use INetworkQueryService to achieve this task:

Please refer this class [NetworkSettings](https://github.com/dzo/packages_apps_phone/blob/master/src/com/android/phone/NetworkSetting.java)

1. onCreate starts the NetworkQueryService and binds it
2. loadNetworksList() tells the service to query for network operators
3. NetworkQueryServiceCallback is evalutated and if the event "EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED" was raised, networksListLoaded will be called to iterate over the available Networks

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16755122/6838146).
Hope this will help you..If you need any help let me know

Comment: is there no other method other than INetworkQueryService,because i tried this thing a while ago and it isn't working.

Comment: @GauravNarwani
Actually i am using same method in my application and it's working perfect..even in latest android version

Comment: can you please send me the code which you are using on my email gauravnarwaaani@gmail.com

Comment: @GauravNarwani, I have contacted you through gmail. please send it to me if you find a solution. thanks