# How get Available mobile networks list

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming

I need to know if the Android API , it possibile  get a list of all the operators mobile  available in the moment and the realite info.
The Android operating system allows us to select the mobile network manually , so this work should be in some API,but I have not yet figured out which may be useful to me.
can someone give me a help to get started ? Especially is this thing possible ?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123697/how-to-get-a-list-of-available-network-providers#answer-3123904. Hope this helps.

Comment: but in this case you should use a private API of Android , how can I do ?

Comment: Networksettings.java